# Synchronizing a requestAnimationFrame callback with a web worker

Tags: javascript, dart

Conceptually I have a requestAnimationFrame callback that look like this:

```
render(now) {
    a = A(now); // long running computation
    b = B(now); // another long running computation
    [update DOM using a, b]
    requestAnimationFrame(render)  // re-trigger animation   
}
```

I would like to run A() in a web worker to increase the frame rate.
Since small inconsistencies in timing are acceptable I would like 
to convert to something like this which runs all computation of
A() in a web worker.

```
render(now) {
    a = [wait for/retrieve previous result for A(now') from web worker]
    [start new computation of A(now) in web worker]
    b = B(now); 
    [update DOM using a, b]
    requestAnimationFrame(render)
}
```

My main problem is with the "wait for/retrieve previous result" part.
Using "await" or similar here causes problems because control can
go back to the browser before the DOM update has taken place.

I am interested in a solution in either Dart or JavaScript.

Comment: Seems like this wouldn't be a problem, as you can't directly manipulate the DOM from inside a worker, you'll have to do that from the main thread, and doing so is synchronus, so nothing to wait for ?

Comment: Note, the call render() is happening in the main thread. The computation of A() does *not* involve any DOM updates.

Comment: @adeneo DOM manipulation is synchronous, but the part you're missing is that talking to the worker is not synchronous, so you have to wait for that.

Comment: @robertmuth I'll be tackling this problem soon, over at https://github.com/trusktr/infamous. The README is for old stuff made with Famous, while my new engine (written from scratch and inspired by Famous) has no usage docs yet. it's in the `motor` folder. The Motor class creates the render loop. Scene and Node classes are for making the a scene graph. I'll add WebGL in the near future, and at that point I'll want to have the scene graph in a worker.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone lands up here looking for ways to use `requestAnimationFrame` from worker, please note that as of 2024 we can use `requestAnimationFrame` method directly from within the worker and that works just fine.